# React CSS mystery: @import only works if at bottom of index.css

Tags: css, reactjs

In a React app, I import index.css in index.js:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Main from "./Main";
import "./index.css";

ReactDOM.render(
  <Main/>, 
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

I also have a secondary css file, secondary.css:

```
.content {
    font-size: 80px;
}
```

which I import in index.css:

```
@import "secondary.css"

.thisClassIsNeverUsed {
}
```

For some reason, this doesn't work (the text in .content divs is normal sized, not 80px). Strangely, if I move the secondary.css import to the *bottom* of index.css, it works:

```
.thisClassIsNeverUsed {
}

@import "secondary.css"
```

Any idea why this is the case? Seems very strange given that CSS imports are supposed to *only* work if they're placed at the top of the file.

EDIT: as another datapoint, if I throw out the React stuff and just open a raw HTML file in my browser:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
</head>

<div class="content">Hello</div>
```

then the .content CSS is not applied regardless of whether the secondary.css import is at the top or the bottom of index.css. I am not well versed in CSS imports, so I don't know if this is expected to work or not.

Comment: do you have another declaration of the .content class in your index.css? If you are importing at the top, then your .content declaration is below that, that declaration could be overwriting your secondary.css one.

Comment: No, I cleaned out index.css and secondary.css so they are just what is copied above. By the way, just updated my question with another datapoint: if I just open a raw HTML file neither import location works. Is this expected?

Comment: are you seeing the network request for the secondary css?

Comment: No, but it is a local file. Do local imports show up in Network tab of the Chrome inspector?

Comment: Every @import should be its own request, yeah.

Comment: This may be caused by an error in one of the CSS files. Mismatched quotes or something. Have you ran your CSS files through a validator? If that doesn't help anything, we definitely need a [mcve].